# how to get Personal Access Token from my integrated application LWC. I am using js only

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using LWC for integration my application. I need to get the Personal Access Token at runtime. Is that possible to get?

Presently, I hardcode Personal Access Token in my LWC application.
like this:

```
Http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

I have `clientId`, `ClientSecret`, `username` and `password`. Can I do auth 2.0 with it?

I am not able to get the Personal Access Token.

Comment: Why not used named credentials?

Comment: I am not creating any class.i am just writing code in javascript file which is lwc component for authorization my application.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of LWC:

> You can’t make calls to Salesforce APIs other than LDS from JavaScript
>   code.

You have to use APEX to make this callout. And even in Apex, it has to used named credentials. You can refer guide [here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/data_api_calls_apex)

SRC for documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/data_api_calls_apex

Comment: I am trying to integrate Asana with lwc. if I am hardcode access token then api call working fine with javascript. but not able to fetch Access token dynamically from asana. because of it auth 2.0 support

Comment: Can you please give me example of that?

Comment: I have no clue about asana, hence I cant help you, neither havent seen anyone integrate Asana with LWC yet so you are on your own for now,